# Is there any way to filter payment_method from magento 1.* ? Ruby Script

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have try to use code

```
@access_token.get("/api/rest/orders?page=1&limit=5&filter[1][attribute]=status&filter[1][in]=processing&filter[2][attribute]=payment_method&filter[2][in]=coinpayments&order=created_at&dir=dsc")
```

But it's not working and the error is

```
=> {"messages"=> {"error"=>[{"code"=>42,
  "message"=>
   "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payment_method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`status` IN('processing')) AND (`payment_method` IN('coinpayments'))"}]}}
```

Does anyone have any ideas to filter payment method?

Comment: Try "_payment_method" instead of payment_method. I'm not sure whether this will work or not, found this when I had a quick look.

Comment: @Nidheesh It's not working. I got 500 error now.